# Extensions Filter ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, jsf, servlets, classnotfoundexception

I want to implement fileUpload like in [BalusC's example](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/02/uploading-files-with-jsf.html).

Unfortunately I already struggle with declaring the servlet.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>Extensions Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>javax.faces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Extensions Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

I am not sure if there is an Extensions filter in `javax.faces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter` but I don't use MyFaces and so I thought mojarra must have the same filter options.

So is that the mistake? If so: Is there a filter in mojarra implementation?

I am getting an ClassNotFoundException!

---

Alright messed up classpaths. It works now, but I get following warnings. (Sry for that german in error logs)

```
WARNUNG: JSF1029:  Die Anwendung hat Version 2.0 (entweder ausdrücklich durch die Version von /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml oder eine fehlende /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), jedoch hängt Klasse 'org.apache.myfaces.custom.aliasbean.AliasBeanTagHandler' von einer Legacy-Facelet-Klasse ab.  Das von dieser Klasse registrierte Facelet-Artefakt wird nicht registriert.
27.01.2011 14:40:41 com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor processComponent
WARNUNG: JSF1029:  Die Anwendung hat Version 2.0 (entweder ausdrücklich durch die Version von /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml oder eine fehlende /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), jedoch hängt Klasse 'org.apache.myfaces.custom.aliasbean.AliasBeansScopeTagHandler' von einer Legacy-Facelet-Klasse ab.  Das von dieser Klasse registrierte Facelet-Artefakt wird nicht registriert.
27.01.2011 14:40:41 com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor processComponent
WARNUNG: JSF1029:  Die Anwendung hat Version 2.0 (entweder ausdrücklich durch die Version von /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml oder eine fehlende /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), jedoch hängt Klasse 'org.apache.myfaces.custom.calendar.HtmlInputCalendarTagHandler' von einer Legacy-Facelet-Klasse ab.  Das von dieser Klasse registrierte Facelet-Artefakt wird nicht registriert.
27.01.2011 14:40:41 com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor processComponent
WARNUNG: JSF1029:  Die Anwendung hat Version 2.0 (entweder ausdrücklich durch die Version von /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml oder eine fehlende /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), jedoch hängt Klasse 'org.apache.myfaces.custom.date.HtmlInputDateTagHandler' von einer Legacy-Facelet-Klasse ab.  Das von dieser Klasse registrierte Facelet-Artefakt wird nicht registriert.
27.01.2011 14:40:41 com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor processComponent
WARNUNG: JSF1029:  Die Anwendung hat Version 2.0 (entweder ausdrücklich durch die Version von /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml oder eine fehlende /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), jedoch hängt Klasse 'org.apache.myfaces.custom.schedule.ScheduleTagHandler' von einer Legacy-Facelet-Klasse ab.  Das von dieser Klasse registrierte Facelet-Artefakt wird nicht registriert.
27.01.2011 14:40:41 com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor processComponent
WARNUNG: JSF1029:  Die Anwendung hat Version 2.0 (entweder ausdrücklich durch die Version von /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml oder eine fehlende /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), jedoch hängt Klasse 'org.apache.myfaces.custom.tabbedpane.HtmlPanelTabbedPaneTagHandler' von einer Legacy-Facelet-Klasse ab.  Das von dieser Klasse registrierte Facelet-Artefakt wird nicht registriert.
27.01.2011 14:40:41 com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor processComponent
WARNUNG: JSF1029:  Die Anwendung hat Version 2.0 (entweder ausdrücklich durch die Version von /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml oder eine fehlende /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), jedoch hängt Klasse 'org.apache.myfaces.custom.tree.taglib.TreeTagHandler' von einer Legacy-Facelet-Klasse ab.  Das von dieser Klasse registrierte Facelet-Artefakt wird nicht registriert.
27.01.2011 14:40:41 com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor processHandlerClass
WARNUNG: JSF1029:  Die Anwendung hat Version 2.0 (entweder ausdrücklich durch die Version von /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml oder eine fehlende /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), jedoch hängt Klasse '[handler-class: null]' von einer Legacy-Facelet-Klasse ab.  Das von dieser Klasse registrierte Facelet-Artefakt wird nicht registriert.
27.01.2011 14:40:41 com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor processHandlerClass
WARNUNG: JSF1029:  Die Anwendung hat Version 2.0 (entweder ausdrücklich durch die Version von /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml oder eine fehlende /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), jedoch hängt Klasse '[handler-class: null]' von einer Legacy-Facelet-Klasse ab.  Das von dieser Klasse registrierte Facelet-Artefakt wird nicht registriert.
27.01.2011 14:40:41 com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor processHandlerClass
WARNUNG: JSF1029:  Die Anwendung hat Version 2.0 (entweder ausdrücklich durch die Version von /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml oder eine fehlende /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), jedoch hängt Klasse '[handler-class: null]' von einer Legacy-Facelet-Klasse ab.  Das von dieser Klasse registrierte Facelet-Artefakt wird nicht registriert.
27.01.2011 14:40:41 com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor processHandlerClass
WARNUNG: JSF1029:  Die Anwendung hat Version 2.0 (entweder ausdrücklich durch die Version von /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml oder eine fehlende /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), jedoch hängt Klasse '[handler-class: null]' von einer Legacy-Facelet-Klasse ab.  Das von dieser Klasse registrierte Facelet-Artefakt wird nicht registriert.
```

Any Idea what that could be?

---

Generic translation:

> The current application uses version 2.0 (either explicitly by `/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml` or a missing `/WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml`), but the class `XXX' uses a legacy Facelet taglib. This class is therefore not registered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extensions filter is not part of standard JSF implementation. It is part of Tomahawk. Why did you change the class name of the filter to make it look like part of standard JSF implementation?

Just use the same as in the article.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>Extensions Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Extensions Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

The article also explicitly mentions that it works perfectly fine in Mojarra. Don't change things on demand because you *think* that it's wrong.

Comment: Oh damn I totally messed that up :-/ Thought the classpath would refer to the myFaces Implementation of jsf -.-

Comment: No, Tomahawk also uses `org.apache.myfaces` package (which is admittedly confusing, they'd better have used `org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk` or so).

Comment: For some reason I get a lot of warnings (pls look my question update)

Comment: In my best German I understand that you're using Tomahawk for JSF 1.2 instead of Tomahawk for JSF 2.0. Is that true? You should download [Tomahawk for JSF 2.0](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk/download.html).

Answer (score 2):

have you added all these jar as he mentioned ?

```
tomahawk-1.1.6.jar
commons-fileupload-1.2.jar
commons-io-1.4.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
commons-el.jar
```